# Why prism's popup window action window content not stretched to it's parent window?

Tags: wpf, prism, popupwindow

I'm using custom popupwindow for show some content to user.

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <mvvm:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding NotificationRequest}">
        <mvvm:PopupWindowAction IsModal="True" CenterOverAssociatedObject="True">
            <mvvm:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
                <views:DataFeedManagerView/>
            </mvvm:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
        </mvvm:PopupWindowAction>
    </mvvm:InteractionRequestTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Everything is works fine until user try to resize popup window. Content will be centered to it's parent window.

[image: Popup Window Screenshot]

For understand what is my fault, i try to explore prism's interactivity samples and i see there is same problem too. How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I want to apologize to you(mm8) because my question is incomplete, so your answer is incomplete too. I understand that after see your answer.

**Why your answer not solve my problem?**
Because my DataFeedManagerView which is have to Width="960" and Height="540" fixed length. There is a items control on the left side when selection is changed, there is content control at the center and its content dynamically changing(of course content size is changing too) vs selection.

**Delayed detailing & solution.**
First xaml in my question from my ShellView, my popup window is DataFeedManagerView which is have Width="960" and Height="540" fixed length. So when i resize popup window it will centered to my user control. So shortly only delete width & height xaml parts from DataFeedManagerView, it will be stretch to popup window content like i want. But after delete, when popup window show on screen, it's size will be too large and again i want to set it's size to fixed values. For solve this also i'll give a style to popup window. So my problem's solution is delete fixed width&height properties from DataFeedManagerView and change ShellView xaml like below;

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <mvvm:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding NotificationRequest}">
        <mvvm:PopupWindowAction IsModal="True" CenterOverAssociatedObject="True">
            <mvvm:PopupWindowAction.WindowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="Window">
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="960"/>
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="540"/>
                </Style>
            </mvvm:PopupWindowAction.WindowStyle>
            <mvvm:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
                <views:DataFeedManagerView/>
            </mvvm:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
        </mvvm:PopupWindowAction>
    </mvvm:InteractionRequestTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

**I hope my question & answer will be help to others. Thanks.**

Answer (score 1):

> How can i solve this problem?

In the official Prism samples it is just a matter of removing the explicit width of the CustomPopupView UserControl. You can do this by setting the Width to `double.NaN`:

```
<prism:PopupWindowAction>
    <prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
        <views:CustomPopupView Width="NaN" />
    </prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
</prism:PopupWindowAction>
```

You should be able to the same for your DataFeedManagerView:

```
<mvvm:PopupWindowAction IsModal="True" CenterOverAssociatedObject="True">
    <mvvm:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
        <views:DataFeedManagerView Height="NaN" Width="NaN" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    </mvvm:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
</mvvm:PopupWindowAction>
```